# Вопрос касательно маппинга в Automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, automapper

Такая ситуация, есть определенные модели, и у этих моделей есть их Dto модели. Например:

```
public class Group
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public Coach Coach { get; set; }
    public int CoachId { get; set; }
    public List<PurchasedSubscription> PurchasedSubscriptions { get; set; }
}
public class GetGroupDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string? Description { get; set; }
}
```

Что если у меня есть модель **A** и **B**. В модели **B** есть свойство типа **A**. У модели **A** так же есть ее Dto модель **ADto**. Я хочу сделать маппинг модели **B** в ее Dto модель **BDto**, но только чтобы вместо свойства типа **A** было свойство типа **ADto** в модели **BDto**.
Выше я описал модель **Group**, она в этой ситуации выступает в роли **ADto**. Вот есть модель **PurchasedSubscription** и ее Dto модель **GetPurchasedSubscriptionDto**.

```
public class PurchasedSubscription
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public Subscription Subscription { get; set; }
    public int SubscriptionId { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }
    public int? GroupId { get; set; }
}
public class GetPurchasedSubscriptionDto
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public GetSubscriptionDto OunSubscription { get; set; } = new();
    public GetGroupDto OunGroup { get; set; } = new();
}
```

То есть мне нужно сделать маппинг **PurchasedSubscription** в **GetPurchasedSubscription**, но при этом чтобы вместо Group было **GetGroupDto**. То есть как бы маппинг, внутри которого еще маппинг.
Пока что я сделал так:

```
public class GroupProfile : Profile
{
    public GroupProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Group, GetGroupDto>();
    }
}

public class PurchasedSubscriptionProfile : Profile
{    
    public PurchasedSubscriptionProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<BuySubscriptionDto, PurchasedSubscription>();
        CreateMap<PurchasedSubscription, GetPurchasedSubscriptionDto>();
    }
}
```

А в самом методе:

```
public async Task<ResponseAPI<GetPurchasedSubscriptionDto>> BuySubscription(BuySubscriptionDto request)
{
    var response = new ResponseAPI<GetPurchasedSubscriptionDto>();
    var userId = int.Parse(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext!.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)!.Value);
    try
    {
        var purchasedSub = _mapper.Map<PurchasedSubscription>(request);
        var subType = await _subRepository.GetById(request.SubscriptionId);
        if (subType!.Duration == "month")
            purchasedSub.EndDate = purchasedSub.StartDate + TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
        else
            purchasedSub.EndDate = DateTime.Now;

        purchasedSub.ClientId = userId;
        await _purSubRepository.Create(purchasedSub);
        response.Data = _mapper.Map<GetPurchasedSubscriptionDto>(purchasedSub);
        response.Data.OunSubscription = _mapper.Map<GetSubscriptionDto>(purchasedSub.Subscription);
        response.Data.OunGroup = _mapper.Map<GetGroupDto>(purchasedSub.Group);
        return response;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        response.Data = null;
        response.Success = false;
        response.Message = ex.Message;
        return response;
    }
}
```

Знаю что делаю неправильно, поэтому хотел бы узнать, как поступать в таких ситуациях.

Comment: По моему скромному мнению, AutoMapper - худшая библиотека во всей экосистеме дотнета. Правильно поступить - избавиться от этого жалкого поделия.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov а что тогда использовать для маппинга? И в целом если знаете как все таки решить данную задачу с помощью этой библиотеки, то напишите все равно пожалуйста

Comment: @Андрей я сам использую AutoMapper, но неоднократно здесь видел, как советуют обычные классы-расширения.

Comment: @Андрей написать свой маппер - дело 5-ти минут. Я обычно делаю `IMapper<TFrom, TTo>` и `IMapper` с `Map<TFrom, TTO>`, который ресолвит внутри `IMapper<TFrom, TTo>`

Comment: @Lapish а с такой ситуацией как у меня не сталкивались ?

Comment: @iikuzmychov спасибо. То есть как бы обычный сервис сделать для маппинга